# U-boot 2016.07: ext4fs_devread read outside partition

Tags: ext4, u-boot

With the latest released U-Boot (2016.07) it suddenly started to produce cryptic error messages like this:

```
U-Boot> ext4load mmc 0:2 ${ramdisk_addr_r} /initramfs.uImage
invalid extent block
ext4fs_devread read outside partition 4294967294
```

Googling leads to [some](http://lists.denx.de/pipermail/u-boot/2014-February/174216.html) old mailing list exchanges related to an actual U-Boot fix done in 2014. So, this information appears to be irrelevant to this issue.

The host side mounts the problematic file system fine. Sometimes uboot succeeds reading files and the key affecting factors are unknown.

Answer (score 3):

(I will leave my answer here for googlers, because it took good three days to figure it out)

The latest and greatest `e2fsprogs` (>1.43) has turned on `64bit` feature for EXT4 filesystems. You can verify whether this is the case with your system by looking into `/etc/mke2fs.conf`. I have these:

```
[fs_types]
        ext4 = {
                features = has_journal,extent,huge_file,flex_bg,64bit,dir_nlink,extra_isize
                inode_size = 256
        }
```

Every filesystem generated with `mkfs.ext4` will thus have `64bit` feature enabled:

```
$ sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sda1 | grep 'Filesystem features:'
Filesystem features:      has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype needs_recovery extent 64bit flex_bg sparse_super large_file huge_file dir_nlink extra_isize
```

The U-Boot will fail to understand this kind of filesystem and until [this](http://git.denx.de/?p=u-boot.git;a=commit;h=6f94ab6656ceffb3f2a972c8de4c554502b6f2b7) commit will bail out with the aforementioned messages.

The fix is to create EXT4 file systems and explicitly disable `64bit` feature on them:

```
$ sudo mkfs.ext4 -O ^64bit /dev/sda1
```

Comment: You also need to disable metadata_csum in the same way.  The next release will see these incompatible features and refuse to mount the filesystem.  It's pretty underwhelming how these new features were rolled out in ext4 :(